# Problemas con creación de diálogo WinAPI, C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Estoy creando un cuadro de diálogo usando las apis de Windows. Como ven a continuación, usé la librería local de recursos para solo definir el cuadro por default. **Mi problema es que en la versión 2017 de Visual Studio funciona perfectamente el código, pero en la 2019** (*estoy trabajando en las dos versiones al mimos tiempo*) **me aparecen errores que no termino de comprender.**

Los códigos de los errores que me aparecen son:

**E0020** /
**C28251** /
**LNK2019** /
**LNK1120**

Ya he investigado un poco y leído respecto a estos errores, pero aún no soy programador muy experimentado. No entiendo cómo funciona perfectamente en la versión 2017, pero crashea en la 2019.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include "resource.h" 
HWND hMenuLogin;

BOOL CALLBACK LoginMenu(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); //Prototipo

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    hMenuLogin = CreateDialog(
        hInst,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
        0,
        LoginMenu
    );

    MSG msg;
    ShowWindow(hMenuLogin, SW_SHOW);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK LoginMenu(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch (msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías poner también tu archivo de cabecera `resource.h` y dar más detalles sobre como estas compilando. Por otra parte, te falta especificar la biblioteca `User32.lib` que es lo más seguro de porqué esos errores.

Yo lo solucioné con `pragma comment` (me gusta compilar desde la línea de comandos) pero tú puedes especificar las bibliotecas desde **visual studio** y ahorrarte el `pragma` si quieres.

```
#include <Windows.h> 

#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

HWND hMenuLogin;

BOOL CALLBACK LoginMenu(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); //Prototipo

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    hMenuLogin = CreateDialog(
        hInst,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
        0,
        LoginMenu
    );

    MSG msg;
    ShowWindow(hMenuLogin, SW_SHOW);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK LoginMenu(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch (msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```